# Вольное обращение с терминами операторы, инструкции, выражения

Tags: java

Ситуация выглядит так, что многие авторы, а правильнее будет сказать переводчики, обращаются с терминами операторы, инструкции, выражения как то уж очень вольно. Мне кажется, особенно непозволительно делать это в учебниках, с самого начала закладывая неправильное представление у изучающих язык. 
Я думаю, необходимо следовать первоисточникам и называть вещи своими именами. Итак, как же эти понятия определены, например, в языке Java? 
Первоисточник говорит о том, что:

1. "Operators are special symbols that perform specific operations on one, two, or three operands, and then return a result". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
2. "An expression is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html
3. "Statements are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement forms a complete unit of execution". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html

Однако почти во всех переводных учебниках, ставших фактически классическими (например, Schildt, Horstmann), понятия операторов и инструкций смешиваются повсеместно. К операторам относят управляющие инструкции (if, switch) и циклы. И это даже несмотря на то, что в оригиналах используется каноническое определение statements. Похоже, что такое заблуждение сложилось давно и if, и switch называют операторами повсеместно. Туда же относят и инструкцию break и метки case. Но почему же тогда операторы называют операторами, если это все разные понятия? Пусть меня поправят, если я в чем то неправ, просто и самому хотелось бы твердо определиться.

Comment: Переводчики переходят с досконально английских определений на эквивалентные русские определения. И тут мы попадаем в такую вещь, что на русский язык "statement" переводится как "оператор" и "инструкция" по смысловому признаку, можно называть обоими вариантами. А слово operator тогда переводится как операция(прим. математическая), но не оператор(!). В итоге мы получаем русские определения аналогичных вещей, а не англицизмы.

Comment: Ну и для общей картины в двух словах, смысловые переводы: operators - операции; expression - выражения; statements - оператор или инструкция. Если идти тем же путем в обратную сторону, расхождений в определениях быть не должно.

Comment: Ну уж этого никак быть не может, поскольку operator и есть оператор, а операция - operation. Кроме того никак нельзя одним и тем же словом переводить два разных понятия operator и statement поскольку в языке им даны разные определения.

Comment: У слов есть много вариантов перевода с одного языка на другой, если вы нашли похожие буквы в словах "operator" и "оператор", то это еще не значит, что они имеют друг к другу хоть какое-либо смысловое отношение. Английское слово не имеет никакого отношения к русскому. Посмотрел в вики, там для вашего вопроса даже [сноску сделали специальную "операция и инструкция"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Операция_(программирование)), что это разные слова.

Comment: Или так: 1. Операции are special symbols that perform specific operations on one, two, or three operands, and then return a result. 2. Выражение is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value. 3. Инструкции/операторы - are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement forms a complete unit of execution. -- примечания -- a) statements переводится как инструкции/операторы b) слова "operators" и "операторы" не имеют ничего общего, случайное совпадение букв.

Comment: Вот мы и пришли к той самой путанице, о которой я говорил. Вот определение из Википедии, о котором Вы упомянули: "Английское слово operator, соответствующее термину «операция», иногда ошибочно переводят как «оператор». На самом деле (по историческим причинам) русский термин «оператор» обозначает то же, что и «инструкция», которой соответствует английское statement". Хорошо, пускай русское слово оператор будет обозначать statement. Но тогда каким русским словом обозначить слово operator? И каким образом эти два понятия разделять?

Comment: Там же и написано `английское слово operator, соответствующее русскому термину «операция»` в программировании. В терминах программирования русские слова "оператор/оператору/оператором" и "операция, операцию, операцией" тоже к друг другу не имеют отношения. Вам просто нужно четко разграничить русские и английские термины и их значения. При этом не вестись на то, что если слова похожи буквами, то наверное они имеют что-то общее, это не так.

Comment: Я не о том. В спецификации языка Java имеется два разных понятия: operator и statement (см. мой вопрос). Мне совершенно не важно как они будут переводиться на русский язык. Пусть хоть банан и яблоко, но они должны быть четко разделены. И я должен четко себе представлять, когда речь идет о банане, а когда о яблоке. В нашем же случае есть только банан, который применяют то по отношению к operator, то по отношению к statement.

Comment: Проверил Шилда электронную версию, у него путаницы нет. У Хорстмана да, одним словом оператор называют вообще любые конструкции языка, но это уже ошибка переводчика который вообще не использует слово "операции" где надо. Хотите, напишите претензию издательству, выпустившему перевод))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59991/discussion-between-alex-krass-and-vitaliy4us).

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто не учитываете, что информационные технологии в Советском Союзе развивались параллельно с западными - и в чем-то даже независимо. Поэтому когда был нужен термин - он зачастую не переводился и не заимствовался, а придумывался.

Сейчас эти термины стали уже классическими, и вошли даже в школьную программу. Поэтому переводить англоязычные термины нужно с учетом их определения, а не дословно:

- operator - операция
- statement - оператор

---

Еще одна причина появления путаницы - тот факт, что одни и те же конструкции в разных языках могут относиться к разным видам. Так, в хорошо известном многим школьникам Паскале есть оператор присваивания (assignment statement) - но в Си-подобных языках вместо него есть операция присваивания (assignment operator). Не все могут уловить отличие между ними при смене языка программирования.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда объясните пожалуйста, чем по Вашему мнению должно быть break, если и оператор и операция предполагают наличие операндов?

Comment: @vitaliy4us оператор не обязательно предполагает наличие операндов. break всегда был оператором.

Comment: "Operators are special symbols that perform specific operations on one, two, or three operands, and then return a result". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @vitaliy4us и чему это противоречит?

Comment: Тому что "оператор не обязательно предполагает наличие операндов", не так ли? И еще, значение слова operator в Оксфордском словаре: "A symbol or function denoting an operation". А всю путаницу вызвало то, что кому то, когда то пришло в голову совершенно безосновательно перевести слово operator как операция. Ну существуют же правила перевода. Никому же не пришло в голову перевести слово молекула как атом, например. Думаю, в этом случае, понимание физики у нас тоже было бы специфическим.

Comment: @vitaliy4us вам надо перестать переводить слово "operator" как "оператор", тогда и противоречия не будет.

Comment: Это все равно как призывать меня писать слово заяц как заец, не обращая внимания на правила языка. Ну что уж там, раз так пишут у нас. А многие используют еще и термины "команда", "директива" и пр. В результате и случилась такая каша, что все запуталось, чему собственно, и был посвящен мой вопрос. И прочитав, например, оригинальную литературу и переводную на одну и ту же тему можно оказаться совершенно сбитым с толку.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, все обстоит даже гораздо хуже, чем я предполагал сначала. Общепринятой русскоязычной спецификации языка Java не существует. Существует официальная англоязычная спецификация, последнее издание которой вышло в 2015 году https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf.

Как мне удалось выяснить, первая неизданная попытка перевода на русский язык была предпринята в 1999 году в славном городе Вологда http://www.uni-vologda.ac.ru/java/jls/ . Именно ею руководствовались мои оппоненты, называя operators операциями, а statements операторами.

Однако, в 2015 году выходит, наконец, печатный перевод http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1875-8.html . И что же мы видим? Ба, все стало на свои места - operators это операторы, а никак не операции, statements - инструкции и т.д. Т.е., все пришло в соответствие со словарем и в русском языке белое стало белым, а черное черным?

Но не все так просто. За все это время было переиздано множество русскоязычных переводов книг по языку Java, в которых все эти термины использовались как Бог на душу положит, и теперь у каждого на этот счет есть свое мнение. И все это не так безобидно как кажется, поскольку является базовыми основами языка. А все, что стоит на непрочном фундаменте, оказывается весьма ненадежным.

А теперь представим ситуацию, когда "воспитанный" на русскоязычной литературе человек, с соответствующей кашей в голове приходит сдавать сертификационный экзамен, который все предпочитают сдавать именно на языке оригинала, поскольку и там перевод играет свою коварную роль. Сколько подножек он встретит на своем пути?

Что же получается в итоге - для того, чтобы разработать хоть сколько-нибудь серьезный продукт, необходима его спецификация. А сам главный инструмент, с помощью которого этот продукт разработан спецификации не имеет, а имеет вольное толкование, не говоря уже о том, что западные коллеги вас могут попросту не понять...

Answer (score -1):

Когда я вижу такие посты - рука тянется к несуществующему маузеру :)

Варианты простого ответа на данные вопрос:

1. Вам ехать или шашечки?
2. Хоть горшком назови, только в печку не ставь

Если сбавить градус дискурса, то я считаю, что это всего лишь вопрос договоренности. Если договорились считать `if/switch` - операторами - я рад за всех, если же наоборот `if/switch` считать инструкциями - ну ок - мы это тоже переварим.

Понять не могу - что от этого меняется то? Ну хорошо, вы вдолбите пятикласснику что такое оператор и что такое инструкция - что изменится?

Вот, искренне не понимаю.

Comment: А Вы ознакомьтесь, например, с вопросами сертификационного экзамена, может быть тогда поймете. Ах, да Вам же ехать! Хотя и в этом случае неплохо было бы знать правила дорожного движения, если Вы, конечно за рулем. Впрочем, и без этого знания половина ездит. Так что up to you.

Comment: Все сдавали на права, но количество ДТП на дорогах только растет==все имеют сертификаты, вот только кодировать мало кто умеет.